# Pushing a mail include to a java program

Tags: java, email, windows-services, windows-server-2008

I have a Windows Server that recives mail. These mail contains only 1 single CSV file. I want my server to automatically take the attachment from any incoming mail and send to a java program locally installed. Is there anyone who can give me directions on any programs that fix this or do I need to create some kind of windows service?

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=>Write a program using threads and run in the Windows Server
=>Your thread will check a particular location (where the CSV will be stored) for every 5 minutes (give your own time interval of checking)
=>Process that file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How do you receive the mail (service,script,application)? If you do via Outlook, things are pretty easy. Write a VBA script which extracts the attachment and saves in a folder somewhere. In the java application you implement a directory listener which fires if the directory has changed and pick up the new file.